# Encoding live video feed with graphics

Tags: video, image-processing, computer-vision

I tried looking this up both on here, and just using google but wasn't able to find a ton of information. I'm a senior in college, and don't have a ton of experience with things outside of Java (though I have no issues with learning new things obviously). I'm ultimately looking to take a live video feed from something like a security camera, and develop software to do something with it. Whether it be drawing lines and shapes on the ground, displaying a logo, or facial recognition, and I have no idea what this type of software development would be considered. As such I don't know what I could look up to learn more about it.

I noticed the following link which had some useful information, but I'm looking to learn a little bit more about things I could do to achieve similar goals. [Displaying a digital "Down Marker" on a live video feed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2381733/displaying-a-digital-down-marker-on-a-live-video-feed)

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

The the field of overlay of artificial forms or model on live video feed is called [Augmented reality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augmented_reality). 
One Open source library that is currently widely used for a number of computer vision related tasks is [OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/) so you could look at it as starting point.

Answer (score 0):

I have one project in which I capture the video with an Osprey card (or similar Windows compatible card), use DirectShow.NET to capture it and get the frames out, use GDI+ to draw on the image, and then display/encode the result for later use.

Something about that is also said here: [Add Watermark to Capture stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4902697/add-watermark-to-capture-stream/4944560#4944560)

It says only something about drawing on the frames, not about detecting something on it - but since you'll be having complete frame encoded in RGB, you'll be able to do your processing at will.